# Conway game of life, Next generation not printing well

Tags: java

I am working on Conway game of college problem. I have been able to print the first generation and the second but when it comes to the following ones they all copy the second generation. I was wondering if y'all can help me out.

```
public void computeNextGeneration(int generation)
{
    char[][] newBoard = new char[board.length][board[0].length];

    for(int i = 0; i < board.length; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < board[0].length; j++)
        {
            if(board[i][j] == '0' && numOfNeighbors(i,j) == 3)
            {
                newBoard[i][j] = 'X';
            }
            else if(board[i][j] == 'X' && numOfNeighbors(i,j) < 2)
            {
                newBoard[i][j] = '0';
            }
             else if(board[i][j] == 'X' && numOfNeighbors(i,j) >3)
            {
                newBoard[i][j] = '0';
            }
             else if(board[i][j] == 'X' && numOfNeighbors(i,j) == 2 || numOfNeighbors(i,j) == 3)
            {
                newBoard[i][j] = 'X'; //change x to 0
            }
             else{
                 newBoard[i][j] +=board[i][j];
             }
        }  
    }


        for (int i = 0; i < newBoard.length; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < newBoard[0].length; j++)
            {
                System.out.print(newBoard[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What output are you getting and what are you expecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you calculate the new board you have to assign it back to the class field `board`. Add as the last line of computeNextGeneration `board = newboard`.

Answer (score 0):

You start counting your generations from 2 `for(int i = 2; i <= gen; i++)` as the constructor doesnt generate a starting generation this should be a *0*.

Comment: I already tried that but it did not work. it was still printing the same thing as the previous one @Dawnkeeper .Thank you tho